# String replacement with pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas column with some strings values like:

```
White bear
Brown Bear
Brown Bear 100 Kg
White bear 200 cm
```

How to check all the strings if they contain the sequence 'White bear' and replace the entire value (not only the sequence) with a string like 'White_bear'?

```
df['Species'] = df['Species'].str.replace('White bear', 'White_bear')
```

did not work right for me because it replaces only the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use boolean indexing:

```
In [173]: df.loc[df.Species.str.contains(r'\bWhite\s+bear\b'), 'Species'] = 'White_bear'

In [174]: df
Out[174]:
             Species
0         White_bear
1         Brown Bear
2  Brown Bear 100 Kg
3         White_bear
```

or bit more general solution:

```
In [204]: df
Out[204]:
             Species
0         White bear
1         Brown Bear
2  Brown Bear 100 Kg
3  White bear 200 cm

In [205]: from_re = [r'.*?\bwhite\b\s+\bbear\b.*',r'.*?\bbrown\b\s+\bbear\b.*']

In [206]: to_re = ['White_bear','Brown_bear']

In [207]: df.Species = df.Species.str.lower().replace(from_re, to_re, regex=True)

In [208]: df
Out[208]:
      Species
0  White_bear
1  Brown_bear
2  Brown_bear
3  White_bear
```

[RegEx explanation](https://regex101.com/r/zdCx9N/1)

Comment: Thanks! Why do whe need this 'r' ,\b and \s? it works also without them

Comment: @ИонСынкетру, those are RegEx special symbols: `\s` - means any space symbol (white space or tab), `\b` - means word boundary, etc.

Comment: `from_re = [r'.*?\bwhite\s+\bbear\b.*', r'.*?\btiger\s+\bbear\b.*',
           r'.*?\bbull\s+\bear\b.*', r'.*?\blue\s+\bear\b.*', r'.*?\blacktip\s+\bear\b.*']`

I've tried to ad another types of bears but for them it did not work. Why?

Comment: I found my error, i have lost a 'b' before blacktip and blue

Comment: I want to find in the same maner all the values that contains digits like : 1.3 m White bear or 11' Bear, but using `r'\d[1-3]+\b\'\s.*'` modify only the digits in the value and doesn't change the entire value like I want. What I do wrong?

Comment: @ИонСынкетру, are you after searching (filtering) or replacing strings/substrings?

Comment: I want to replace all the values that contains any digits to "Unknown"

Comment: @ИонСынкетру, does that mean that `White bear 200 cm` from your sample DF should be replaced with `Unknown`?

Comment: Yes, if I use `r'.*?\d.?*` it changes only the numeric part of the string like: `White bear Unknown cm`

Comment: Try this: `r'.*\d+.*'`